# Wrap text when displaying text as an image in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Say I have some long text

```
(define EXTREMELY-LONG-TEXT "foo foo ...(like 25 times)... foo")
```

and I need to draw it to a background that is constrained on the x axis but not the y axis. Is there anyway to limit the x direction of the text and have it expand downward by default? Or do I have to define my own function to accomplish this task?

Currently, I have a text adventure game with changing lengths of text and I want to be able to define a constant x for the game to be run at instead of having to define a large background for it to be drawn onto such as

```
(define BG (empty-scene 500 100))
(overlay/align "center" "top" (text EXTREMELY-LONG-TEXT 16 "black") BG)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it yourself, but that shouldn't be difficult.

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/image)

(define TEXT-SIZE 16)
(define WIDTH 500)
(define limit (exact-floor (* 2.4 (/ WIDTH TEXT-SIZE))))

(define EXTREMELY-LONG-TEXT (string-append* (make-list 25 "foo ")))

(define (fit-string s)  
  (string-append*
   (map list->string
        (add-between (sequence->list (in-slice limit (string->list s)))
                     '(#\newline)))))

(define BG (empty-scene WIDTH 100))
(overlay/align
 "center" "top"
 (text (fit-string EXTREMELY-LONG-TEXT) TEXT-SIZE "black") BG)
```

The formula `2.4 * WIDTH / TEXT-SIZE` can be improved further, but it works well enough for this case.